# VSCode - auto_prepend_file for code suggestions

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been using VS code instead of eclipse for the last few weeks and find it much quicker, easier to use. However there is one thing I can’t seem to figure out.
My php app calls a prepend file which initiates a class called `GlobalClass`:

`$gc = new GlobalClass();`

When I type `$gc->` in eclipse I get all the functions prompted. This doesn’t work within VS Code.
If I add use `GlobalClass` or add the `$gc = new GlobalClass();` to the top of the file then it works. Is there any way to declare this within VS Code or to point the editor to the code within the prepend file?

Comment: You ever figure this out?